# How to check the generated token doesn't exist yet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a method that creates a token. This worked and now I want to also ensure uniqueness of the token. Therefore I added `while self.class.exists?(api_digest: api_digest)` (see below). However, now all sorts of test fail with the error:

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)

referring to `def remember_api(type, user)` which is in a sessions helper. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

---

User model:

```
def remember_api
  self.api_token = User.new_token  # Creates new api_token.
  update_attributes(api_digest: User.digest(api_token), api_sent_at: Time.zone.now)
end while self.class.exists?(api_digest: api_digest)

def User.new_token
  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

def User.digest(string)
  cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST : BCrypt::Engine.cost
  BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
end
```

Sessions helper:

```
def remember_api(type, user)
  if type == "user"
    user.remember_api
  end
end
```

**Update:** So I tried the method below. But that doesn't seem to work either as it gets into an infinite loop.

```
def remember_api
  begin
    self.api_token = User.new_token
    update_attributes(api_digest: User.digest(api_token), api_sent_at: Time.zone.now)
  end while self.class.exists?(api_digest: api_digest)
end
```

---

**Update2:** I've got model validation for uniqueness on `api_digest` and tried the following:

```
def remember_api
  begin
    self.api_token = User.new_token
    api_digest = User.digest(api_token)
    debugger
  end until update_attributes(api_digest: api_digest, api_sent_at: Time.zone.now)
end
```

This goes wrong, again creating an infinite loop. It proofs that once I move `update_attributes` behind the `end`, debugger shows that `api_digest` and `api_token` are `nil`. And `self` returns: `User(id: integer, email: string, username: string, fullname: string, ...`. If I place `update_attributes` inside the `begin...end` (below debugger), they are not `nil` and `self` returns: `<Userid: 1001, email: "mymail@example.com", username: "mystring1", ...`.

Comment: I don't think `def ... end while` does what you think it does. If the condition you put after `while` evaluates to `false`, the method will not be defined, and if it evaluates to `true` the method will be defined over and over again (until it evaluates to `false`).

Comment: What [Jordan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/179125/jordan) said - create a separate `begin`/`end while self.class.exists?...` inside the `User#remember_api` method.

Comment: Thanks! I've added what I believe you're suggesting as an update to the OP.

Comment: I've added a second update that explains the cause of the problem. Would you perhaps have a suggestion what to compare then in the `exists?` line?

Comment: @Jordan, but how would I change it so that if it evaluates to `true` it moves on (except when the digest is `nil`)? I'm implementing from this tutorial: https://www.amberbit.com/blog/2014/2/19/building-and-documenting-api-in-rails/

Comment: Do what @mikej said and put it inside your method. You want that loop to happen inside your method; you don't want your method to be defined in a loop.

Comment: I do apologize @Jordan for this misunderstanding from my side. But I really don't understand what you mean. In update2 `begin ... end while` is inside `def remember_api ... end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `api_digest` should be `self.api_digest`. It is because it is looking for a local variable called api_digest, but you meant an attribute on this model

Like this:

```
def remember_api
  begin
    self.api_token = User.new_token
    update_attributes(api_digest: User.digest(api_token), api_sent_at: Time.zone.now)
  end while self.class.exists?(api_digest: self.api_digest)
end
```

**Update**

When you call `update_attributes`, it will return true if it updates and passes validation. Then it'll go ahead and check if it exists and it does because you just updated it in there, so it'll loop again and lead to infinite loop

If `update_attributes` returns false, that means it exists and meet the while statement and loop. This is the only time it does what you expected.

```
begin
  self.api_token = User.new_token
  self.api_digest = User.digest(api_token)
end while self.class.exists?(api_digest: self.api_digest)
self.api_sent_at = Time.zone.now
self.save!
```

Doc: [update](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update)

Comment: Thank you for thinking along. Unfortunately, changing it to `self.api_digest` made no difference.

Comment: Ah, I think I know why. You call `update_attributes` before you check, so it always exists

Comment: It wouldn't evaluate to `true` if it wasn't unique because then model validation wouldn't have allowed it to save. But what I don't understand is that if `exists?` evaluates to `true`, the method doesn't move on; instead it starts all over again creating an infinite loop.

Comment: The `exists?` check will be finding the user itself that you've just updated so will always return true. You'll need to add a check like `id` is not `self.id` i.e. Is there some other user with this API digest?

Comment: Or just add a uniqueness validation to the model and check for `update_attributes` returning false instead of using `exists?`

Comment: Yes, I've got model validation for uniqueness on `api_digest`. But using `update_attributes` to create the loop, generates another issue (see update 2 in post).